# ffmpeg generate thumbnails on GPU

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, scale, thumbnails, nvidia

I try to generate thumbnails with acceleration on GPU, so compile ffmpeg 3.4.1 and run command:

```
./ffmpeg  -i ~/Videos/1080.mp4 -vf "hwupload_cuda,thumbnail_cuda=100,scale_cuda=107:60,hwdownload,format=yuv420p" -vframes 1 -y ~/Videos/thumbs/thumb%03d.jpg
```

But I get wrong output picture (the color of thumbnail is green):

[image]

Correct image must be black.
How to make first image with correct color?

[image]

log: -loglevel verbose

```
ffmpeg version N-89707-g89b84cb Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --cpu=native --enable-pthreads --extra-version=hd --enable-gnutls --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-swscale --enable-libx264 --enable-version3 --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-cuda-sdk --enable-filter=scale_cuda --enable-filter=thumbnail_cuda --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7. 11.100 /  7. 11.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
[h264 @ 0x392ed40] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/alex/Videos/1080.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2012-05-30T20:01:34.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:14.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5476 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 1920x1080 (1920x1088), 5321 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-05-30T20:01:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x3a38280] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[Parsed_thumbnail_cuda_1 @ 0x4e3d8c0] batch size: 100 frames
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x4e8b640] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/60000 fr:30000/1001 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x4e8ca00] w:iw h:ih flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[format @ 0x4e8b540] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scaler_0' between the filter 'Parsed_format_4' and the filter 'format'
[Parsed_scale_cuda_2 @ 0x4e89380] w:1920 h:1080 -> w:107 h:60
[swscaler @ 0x4ebf0c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x4e8ca00] w:107 h:60 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 -> w:107 h:60 fmt:yuvj420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
Output #0, image2, to '/home/alex/Videos/thumbs/thumb%03d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.3.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, 1 reference frame, yuvj420p(pc, left), 107x60, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.9.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[Parsed_thumbnail_cuda_1 @ 0x4e3d8c0] frame id #76 (pts_time=2.535867) selected from a set of 100 images
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame=    1 fps=0.9 q=3.1 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:02.56 bitrate=N/A speed=2.26x    
video:2kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (/home/alex/Videos/1080.mp4):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 115 packets read (134655 bytes); 101 frames decoded; 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 1 packets read (9 bytes); 
  Total: 116 packets (134664 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (/home/alex/Videos/thumbs/thumb%03d.jpg):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 1 frames encoded; 1 packets muxed (1864 bytes); 
  Total: 1 packets (1864 bytes) muxed
```

**UPDATE, working!**
Add format=nv12 before hwupload

`-vf "format=nv12,hwupload_cuda,thumbnail_cuda,scale_cuda=1280:72‌​0,hwdownload,format=‌​nv12"`

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Nothing special in log, as usually printed standard output.

Comment: Still share it.

Comment: Added  log to question.

Comment: So no solution?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this Q. Will look at it soon.

Comment: Remove the thumbnail filter and scale to a larger size, and see if the issue remains.

Comment: No luck. I'm trying  `"hwupload_cuda,scale_cuda=640:360,hwdownload,format=yuv420p"` but steel getting green image.

Comment: But if I replace scale_cuda to scale_npp then I get GOOD image.
`"hwupload_cuda,thumbnail_cuda,scale_npp=640:360,hwdownload,format=yuv420p"`

Comment: Add `format=nv12` before hwupload.

Comment: WORK! `-vf "format=nv12,hwupload_cuda,thumbnail_cuda,scale_cuda=1280:720,hwdownload,format=nv12"`
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The best way for this situation is decoding on GPU. It will improve performance as the CPU will be less loaded. You can do it with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i video_source \
       -vf "thumbnail_cuda=2,scale_cuda=107:60,hwdownload,format=nv12" \
       -vframes 1 frame.jpg
```

Also will be better make a resize at the decoding step like follow:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -resize 107x60 -i video_source \
       -vf "thumbnail_cuda=2,hwdownload,format=nv12" \
       -vframes 1 frame.jpg
```

These commands show how to decode h264 video, if you need to decode mpeg2, hevc, vp8, vp9, vc1 then you can choose an appropriate decoder from the list below:

```
ffmpeg -decoders | grep cuvid
 V..... h264_cuvid           Nvidia CUVID H264 decoder (codec h264)
 V..... hevc_cuvid           Nvidia CUVID HEVC decoder (codec hevc)
 V..... mjpeg_cuvid          Nvidia CUVID MJPEG decoder (codec mjpeg)
 V..... mpeg1_cuvid          Nvidia CUVID MPEG1VIDEO decoder (codec mpeg1video)
 V..... mpeg2_cuvid          Nvidia CUVID MPEG2VIDEO decoder (codec mpeg2video)
 V..... mpeg4_cuvid          Nvidia CUVID MPEG4 decoder (codec mpeg4)
 V..... vc1_cuvid            Nvidia CUVID VC1 decoder (codec vc1)
 V..... vp8_cuvid            Nvidia CUVID VP8 decoder (codec vp8)
 V..... vp9_cuvid            Nvidia CUVID VP9 decoder (codec vp9)
```

Comment: What's the point of using GPU accelerated decode for thumbnail generation? Total ffmpeg execution time on GPU is around 0,5 sec, and CPU is 0.01s. It's totally pointless, unless you want to generate tons of JPEG

Comment: Also about tons of JPEG, it may also make no sense. JPEG encoding is still on CPU, and decoding is much faster than encoding. Add heavy hwdownload operation. CPU will always be faster than GPU "accelerated" approach.

Comment: Great answer Ivan. I was wondering, where did you find about `thumbnail_cuda`? I'd like to know more about it but google returns only your answers (here and on video.stackexchange) and I can't find anything on the official docs (either ffmpeg or nvidia).

Comment: Add `-hwaccel_output_format cuda` after `-hwaccel cuvid` on more recent builds. W/o it currently gives *«WARNING: defaulting hwaccel_output_format to cuda for compatibility with old commandlines. This behaviour is DEPRECATED and will be removed in the future. Please explicitly set "-hwaccel_output_format cuda".»*